# Guile Schemeでニュートン法を実行しようとしたが、エラーが出て実行できない。

Tags: scheme

Guile Schemeで以下のようなニュートン法のコードを実行しようとしているのですが、エラーが出て実行できません。エラーの原因が分からず、改善ができないのでどなたか改善方法が分かれば教えていただけると助かります。

```
(define (deriv f dx)
  ;;;導関数
  (lambda (x)(exact->inexact(/ (- (f (+ x dx)) (f x)) dx))))
(define (good-enough? g guess)
  ;;;guessが十分良い値かを確かめる。
  (< (abs (g guess)) 0.0000001))
(define (improve g guess)
  ;;;guessの値を改善する。
  (- guess (exact->inexact(/ (g guess) ((deriv g 0.0001) guess)))))
(define (newton-iter2 g guess)
  ;;;ニュートン法
  (if (good-enough? g guess)
      guess
      (newton-iter2 g (improve g guess))))
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (sqrt-base x)
  ;;;誤差を返す関数
  (lambda (t) (- (square t) x)))
```

上のような関数をEmacsのスクリプト内で定義しguileに読み込ませた上で、以下のコードをguileに実行させたいのですがエラーが直せません...。
(2の平方根を求めたい。)

```
(define (sqrt3 x) (newton-iter2 (sqrt-base x) 1.0))
(sqrt3 2)
```

以下のようなエラーが出続けています...。

```
<unnamed port>:11:0: In procedure sqrt3:
In procedure module-lookup: Unbound variable: newton-iter2
```

Comment: 実行環境やどのようにしてプログラムを実行したかを追記したほうが回答がつきやすいと思います。(実際Racketで試したところ特にエラーはでませんでした）

Comment: 返信頂きありがとうございます！ご指摘の通り、実行環境に関する情報を追記させて頂きました！

Comment: おそらく「Emacsのスクリプト内で定義しguileに読み込ませた」の部分で何かしらおかしくなっているのだと思います。手順を箇条書きなどでより詳しく書いてみてくださいませんか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guileにはモジュールシステムがありますが、`load`した定義ファイルにモジュール指定の記述がないため、REPLのモジュールとは別のモジュールに定義されたのが原因だと思います。

定義時のモジュールと呼び出し時のモジュールを一致させるか、モジュールを指定して呼び出す必要があります。

(なお、`load`でモジュールを何も指定しないと`(ice-9 popen)`モジュールが設定されるようです。)

### REPLのデフォルト`guile-user`モジュールに定義を合わせる

```lisp
;; 定義ファイル
(use-modules (guile-user))

(define (deriv f dx) ...
```

```lisp
;; REPL
scheme@(guile-user)> (load "file.scm")
scheme@(guile-user)> (define (sqrt3 x) (newton-iter2 (sqrt-base x) 1.0))
scheme@(guile-user)> (sqrt3 2)
$1 = 1.4142135624530596
```

### ロードするファイルにモジュールを定義し、モジュールの外から呼び出す

```lisp
;; 定義ファイル
(define-module (ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59323)
  #:export (newton-iter2 sqrt-base)) ; newton-iter2 と sqrt-baseを公開

(define (deriv f dx) ...
```

```lisp
;; REPL
(load "file.scm")

(define (sqrt3 x)
  ((@ (ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59323) newton-iter2) ;ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59323モジュールで公開されているnewton-iter2を指定
   ((@ (ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/59323) sqrt-base) x) 1.0))
scheme@(guile-user)> (sqrt3 2)
$1 = 1.4142135624530596
```

### 参考

- https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Modules.html

Comment: 返信頂き有難うございます！2番目の方法はよく分かりませんでしたが、1番目の方法で上手く動作しました...!